# Cannot invoke method propertyMissing() in Groovy

Tags: groovy, geb

I am getting `Cannot invoke method propertyMissing()` error while trying to take screenshots in Geb.

Following are the classes

### MyLoginPage.groovy

```
package geb.pages

import geb.Page

class MyLoginPage extends Page {
    static url = "https://JSPNet.com/entry"
    static at = { title == "My Login" }

....
signIn { $("#btnEnter span")}

    def getScreenshots(){

        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)DriverInstance).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE)  ***** Error line ****
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"))
    }
}
```

I am getting this error in the above class in relating to `DriverInstance`

### GebConfig.groovy

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver


driver = {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\MyFolder\\selenium-2.32.0\\chromedriver.exe")
    def newdriver = new ChromeDriver()
    DriverInstance = newdriver
    return newdriver
}

environments {
    chrome { driver = { new ChromeDriver() } }
    firefox {driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }}
}

waiting {timeout = 5}
```

### MyHomePage.groovy

```
And(~'^hit the Login button$') { ->

     page.signIn.click()

    MyLoginPage = new MyLoginPage()
    MyLoginPage.getScreenshots()

}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method propertyMissing() on null object
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:77)
                at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
                at 

org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
 at geb.pages.MyLoginPage.getScreenshots(MyLoginPage.groovy:70)
                at geb.pages.MyLoginPage$getScreenshots.call(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: And(~'^hit the Login button$') { ->

Is the -> operator a typo?

Comment: It's an operator use in cucumber step definition file.

Comment: Ahh ok. Unfortunately I don't know cucumber well at all.

Comment: Is MyLoginPage a variable and if so should it have the same name as the class. Specifically MyLoginPage =

Comment: No worries error is not relating to cucumber. To you question. I am trying to create an object of `MyLoginPage.groovy ` class and call that method `getScreenshots() ` there

Comment: Is `page` null on the `page.signIn.click()` line

Comment: Cant you do it the gebish way in the click method? 

And(~'^hit the Login button$') { ->

    page.signIn.click(MyLoginPage)    
    page.getScreenshots()

} Put new lines in too.

Comment: `page.signIn.click ` method is there in `MyLoginPage.groovy ` I didn't add into the question. Because I thought its not relevant. Added now

Comment: @twinj Thank you, As you specified, can access the method in gebish way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `DriverInstance` is null. You should be able to access driver with `driver` property:

```
def getScreenshots(){

    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE)
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"))
}
```

Comment: Perfect. BTW should I include this method in all Page objects groovy class on order to get screenshots Or is there an alternative way

Comment: Further, Is returning part is necessary ? i.e. `return newdriver `

Comment: I'm not an expert in Geb so it should be probably better to do it gebish way as @twinj suggested.
Regarding returning from this closure: yes, you need to return driver instance here. Take look at docs: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/configuration.html#configuration